# Custom attributes in SDF files

Tags: gazebo-10, sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Is it possible to add custom attributes to SDF elements other than plugins?  For example should I be able to do:

```
<model>
    <my_random_thing>5</my_random_thing>
    ...
</model>
```

and then be able to access my_random_thing from the SDF element associated with my model?  I know this works for plugins, but I can't get it to work for models.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24430/custom-attributes-in-sdf-files/) by [Jenny B](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/12896/jenny-b/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-02-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kumpakri](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6511/kumpakri/) on 2020-02-10**:
If you use ROS with your system you can save "your random thing" on rosparam server to access it from nodes and plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Reading the specification, I'd say it's not possible.

You can do this for plugins due to the [copy_data](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat/src/a31f8377a5dbff496c387468863a742b1a66dd7a/sdf/1.6/plugin.sdf#lines-10) element, which is not part of the model spec.

---

Originally posted by [nlamprian](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/8391/nlamprian/) with karma: 833 on 2020-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2